# Javascript logical operators not working in R shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny

So I have been struggling to add a condition to my R shiny application once scrolling a certain distance. After lots of debugging, I have at least realized one initial issue blocking my path. The logical operator in javascript is not working. Below is an incomplete toy example, but hopefully you don't need a working example to figure out what is going on.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  ...
  tags$body(
   ...
     tags$script('
                  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
                  function myFunction() {
                    var x = 5;
                    var y = 3;
                    if(y < x){
                      sidebar.classList.add("stickyTop");
                    }
                  }')
)))
```

If I remove the if portion, the "stickyTop" characteristics get added once I scroll at all. Leaving, what seems like an obviously true statement in an if statement, does not activate "stickyTop". Using other variables, moving them outside the function, or anything else I have tried is not working.

Using if(1) works, if(true) works too, if(0<1) does not. What am I doing wrong?

For those curious, my "stickyTop" is defined in my css file:

```
.stickyTop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Longer code (not quite  working MWE, having a hard time trimming my code down, randomly included part of another MWE):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- (fluidPage(fluidRow(
  id = "title",
  column(
    8,
    titlePanel(
      title = div(strong("Stuff"),
                  style = "color:black;"),
      windowTitle = "Mores tuff"
    ),
    p("Last updated on June 22, 2018", id = "id_updated_time"),
    br()
  )#,),

  tags$body(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      id = "sidebar",
      actionButton("evReactiveButton", "eventReactive"),
      br(),
      actionButton("obsEventButton", "observeEvent"),
      br(),
      actionButton("evReactiveButton2", "eventReactive2")
    ),
    mainPanel(#style="position:sticky;",
      verbatimTextOutput("eText"),
      verbatimTextOutput("oText")),

    tags$script(
      '
      window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

      function myFunction() {
      var x = 5;
      var y = 3;
      if(1){
      sidebar.position.fixed;
      }
      }'
    )
    ) # Close sidebarLayout
    ) # Close tags$body
    )))

  server <- function(input, output) {
    etext <- eventReactive(input$evReactiveButton, {
      runif(1)
    })
    observeEvent(input$obsEventButton, {
      output$oText <- renderText({
        runif(1)
      })
    })
    eventReactive(input$evReactiveButton2, {
      print("Will not print")
      output$oText <- renderText({
        runif(1)
      })
    })
    output$eText <- renderText({
      etext()
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: what do you mean by works? `if(0){sidebar.classList.add("stickyTop");}` and that still adds the class name?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, meant "if(1)" applies the changes (sidebar is the id of my sidebarPanel portion of sidebarLayout). So the "position:fixed" part of the css file makes it fixed to the window as I scroll.

Comment: can you post your original code, it looks like there is something else we are missing here. Because the simple `if` statement should run like `if(1>0)`

Comment: Attached a nearly MWE, sorry it has been a super long day trying to figure this and other stuff out. I will try to get more details after my commute.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, weekend was busier than expected. Just got around to fixing my MWE example and then saw the below answer (my MWE had the same issues as my code and is fixed with the addition of the HTML tag). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to put the javascript in einem `HTML` tag.

```
tags$script(HTML(
        '
        function myFunction() {
        var x = 5;
        var y = 3;
        if(y < x){
        $("#sidebar").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "0",
        "height": "100vh",
        });
        }
        }

        window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};'
    ))
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I changed you javascript just for my testing

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I somehow overlooked that as other things following tags also use the HTML tag too.